# MMU implementation

Tags: linux, windows, architecture

Short question: where does page table reside? Is it in MMU (totally hardware implementation) or in RAM (OS involved)?

I am trying to figure out whether the RAM access involved in mapping linear address onto physical in case of TLB miss. I guess the answer in "no" and implementation is totally hardware, but I am not sure. I saw mention that it can be as hardware as software, but I am interested in common case of Intel processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLB in Intel architecture is handled in the hardware.  [This paper from intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/vtune/performance_analysis_guide.pdf) references the TLB implementation.